# Symfony validation, are parameters ignored in definition files (xml, yml)?

Tags: symfony

I need to use the `%cart.class%` parameter in my validation.xml file (because can be changed through the configuration). Is this possible?

The following **is not working**, no errors about parameter being ignored:

```
<class name="%cart.class%">
    <constraint name="CartBundle\Validation\Constraints\Cart" />
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the service container configuration with the validation configuration. The validator configuration doesn't support parameters.

I assume you've got a Cart interface or a base class (otherwise you wouldn't be able to rely on this type being passed around). The configured Cart class should inherit validation constraints from the base class. I haven't tried this with an interface (would be a shame if it didn't work).